# Low Latency for Google compared to servers located with in my country

Tags: ping, latency

When i ping google.co.in

its showing 11.1 ms as average

```
ping www.google.co.in
PING www.google.co.in (173.194.36.63) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from bom04s02-in-f31.1e100.net (173.194.36.63): icmp_req=1 ttl=58 time=11.1 ms
64 bytes from bom04s02-in-f31.1e100.net (173.194.36.63): icmp_req=2 ttl=58 time=11.1 ms
```

But y is it faster than servers located in my country,google doesnot have any Data centers in My country.

```
PING cusat.ac.in (210.212.233.54) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 210.212.233.54: icmp_req=1 ttl=59 time=159 ms
64 bytes from 210.212.233.54: icmp_req=2 ttl=59 time=157 ms
```

and i heard of caching with CDN whcih gives fast response but in this case ping is not showing anything in between and response time is even better than servers located in my country.

**traceroute**

```
traceroute to 173.194.36.63 (173.194.36.63), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1  10.10.11.33 (10.10.11.33)  0.358 ms  0.316 ms  0.318 ms
2  115.124.115.66 (115.124.115.66)  159.941 ms  159.957 ms  160.361 ms
3  121.240.71.249.static-pune.vsnl.net.in (121.240.71.249)  5.869 ms  5.870 ms  5.857 ms
4  115.113.165.98.static-mumbai.vsnl.net.in (115.113.165.98)  6.823 ms  6.815 ms  6.786 ms
5  72.14.232.202 (72.14.232.202)  6.775 ms  6.759 ms  6.742 ms
6  209.85.241.189 (209.85.241.189)  7.419 ms  7.047 ms  7.014 ms
7  bom04s02-in-f31.1e100.net (173.194.36.63)  7.907 ms  7.888 ms  8.287 ms
```

Comment: Not sure what do you want, but with the 'tracert' command, you will get all steps of the transmision and the routers. Then just geo-find that IP to know the countries.

Comment: @Carlos Why there is very less latency in between my computer and google server which is located far form my country.Even better response then Server located in my country.I heard of CDN to achieve this,but in this case there is no intermediate server coming in between.Do u have any idea?

Comment: No sorry, I dont really knows who can a packet travel faster to a longer distance than to a short one... Will be nice to know the reason. ¿Anyone?

Comment: Many reasons, but here's a possible one: the google servers have giant uncongested pipes to them; your packet and its reply can travel between your NSP and google without any lossage and consequent retransmission delays.  If you're sure that the 160-ms RTTs are in your own country, then I'd have to say the pipes to those might well be mightily congested, because unless your country stretches from here to L-1, speed-of-light time is not the dominant component of RTT.

Comment: What makes you think Google has no data centers in your country? That IP address is listed as being in Mumbai.

Comment: @MichaelHampton 173.194.36.63 ? as per whatsmyip.com its showing "GEORGIA".and so far i haven't heard about any Google Data centre in india.

Comment: Obviously that random website (which doesn't seem to work properly) is giving wrong information.

Comment: @MichaelHampton but from where did u get that ip location information.

Comment: From Google, of course. And from traceroute. Since Google doesn't _own_ its own datacenter in India (yet), this is probably space they're leasing.

Comment: As you can see from your own traceroute, the packets enter Google's network in Mumbai.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I am still confused,How did you figure it out that its from Mumbai.Is that because of name "bom04s02-in-f31.1e100.net",some googling shows that google register their IP in US so "IP-to-location databases and whois" lookup wont show real locations.So whatsmyip is showing wrong information.

Comment: Because it _says_ `mumbai` on hop 4, and hop 5 is Google's IP address. By the laws of physics, we can deduce that this bit of Google's network is being hosted by (or physically very close to) the ISP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the bandwidth is restricted, packets have to wait their turn, when bandwidth is not, they can travel at the actual line speed (or as close as tech allows). You're just seeing the difference in connectivity, google will probably be connected in data centers near peering points, the other servers you're pinging are probably not as close to a backbone.